# How to update quantity into order summary at checkout page?

Tags: quantity, magento2.3.0, checkout-page, order-summary

Magento Version : 2.3.0

As per client requirement, i need to update quantity from order summary at checkout page.

Please suggest me, how can i implement this functionality?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried So far?

Comment: I tried to doing this functionality as customization like put input box instead of quantity with increment and decrement  (+,-) button in order summary HTML file. 

But i am not able to set increment quantity value into current text box and also not able to define our custom jQuery function into that section's javascript file.

Please suggest me, what to do for achieve this functionality?

Comment: Hi have you found any solution for this?